Unexpected Multi-Line Scroll Jump After Switching Windows
I’m encountering a strange scrolling issue on Ubuntu. Whenever I switch to a new application (for example, from VS Code to a web browser) and immediately scroll, the page jumps by several lines at once (almost like 2-3 scroll steps in a single move). If I stay in the same window and scroll normally, everything behaves just fine-smooth, one-line scrolling.
I’ve searched for similar topics but couldn’t find anything that exactly matches this problem. Toggling smooth scrolling and tweaking various scroll settings hasn’t helped so far. This behavior occurs regardless of whether I’m using a mouse wheel or a touchpad gesture.
I’d really appreciate any advice on diagnosing or fixing this issue.
Thanks a lot.
